# Can't get value from attribute "eancode"

Tags: attributes, php, csv

I want to export some orders from Magento 1.7, but I'm stuck on 1 thing. I have an attribute in Magento, named 'eancode'. I want to put the eancode from every product in the export, but it shows a blank field. I checked that the attribute contains some numbers for the exported products.

In csv.php I have:

> ```
> /**
>  * Returns the item specific values.
>  * 
>  * @param Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item $item The item to get values from
>  * @param Mage_Sales_Model_Order $order The order the item belongs to
>  * @return Array The array containing the item specific values
>  */
> protected function getOrderItemValues($item, $order, $itemInc=1) 
> {
>     return array(
>         $itemInc,
>         $this->geteancode($item),
>         $item->getName(),
>     );
> }
> ```
>
> }

In abstractcsv.php I have:

> ```
> /**
>  * EAN code output
>  *
>  * @param Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item $item The item to return info from
>  * @return String The ean
>  */
> protected function geteancode($item)
> {
> $eancode = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProduct()->getId())->geteancode();
> return $item->geteancode();
> }
> ```

Can you see what's going wrong? I've been troubleshooting and Googling for hours now, but I can't find the problem.

Thank you!

Comment: Change this `return $item->geteancode();` to this `return $eancode`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see two issues with your code:

1. Even though you may have named the attribute in lower case, you will still need to refer to it in your `get` method using [CamelCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase), for example:

   ```
   $eancode = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProduct()->getId())->geteancode();
   ```
2. In the first line of `protected function geteancode($item)` function, you retrieve the ean value, and then you return the `geteancode()` function again on the following line which would return an empty String.

Your method should read:

```
  protected function geteancode($item)
 {
     return Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProduct()->getId())->getEancode();
 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This works great! Again something learned about PHP. :) I can't give you points now, because I don't have 15 reputation, but I will do if I have!

Answer (score 0):

In the `Abstractcsv.php` the following line should be corrected

```
$eancode = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProduct()->getId())->geteancode();
```

should be

```
$eancode = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProduct()->getId())->getEancode();
```

Also I think it should return the `$eancode` variable and not the `$item-geteancode()`.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer! I can't give you points now, because I don't have 15 reputation, but I will do if I have!

Comment: No problem, glad to have helped :)